# Random stroke width change (using Brush Tool)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

I'm getting these random variations in my path's stroke and it's driving me crazy not knowing how to fix it. Anyone have any ideas? I want no style to this stroke but it seems to be going wonky in some parts, this one in the screenshot is a good example of what I'm experiencing:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help or tips =)

Comment: New Development: I tried to continue with my project to keep moving the path nodes to where I need the lines - assuming someone can help me solve the stroke issue - but when I try to use the bezier handles to adjust the curvature the lines keep changing stroke width. I've tried to go into preferences to scale strokes and effects to see if that would change anything, but no luck with that.

Comment: Are you *intentionally* using the calligraphy brush you have selected in the screenshot? Are you drawing with a brush? Have you tried just selecting "Basic" (Which means no brush stroke)?

Comment: Where are you seeing that @Scott? I thought I was using a uniform or basic brush... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot shows a **calligraphic brush** clearly selected in the Control Bar. It also states "**5 pt. Round**" in the Control Bar. "**Uniform**" refers to the stroke width profile, but brushes have some dynamic abilities in addition to any width profiles.

[image]

To remove the brush dynamics which are most likely the reason your stroke widths are varying.... Click where it reads .'5pt Round..  and then click the **Basic** option (which means "*basic path, remove brush strokes*").

This should result in a standard stroke path with a uniform width along it.

If you wish to draw freehand but *not* use brush dynamics, you need to be certain to click "Basic" for your brush paths after they are drawn... or use the Pencil or Freeform Pen tools rather than a brush.

Comment: I selected my paths and selected the "Basic" stroke profile. Guess what worked? Haha. Thanks man, I can't believe it was something so simple. I honestly didn't know that I was using a calligraphy brush.. :/